# Getting runtime exception when working with UIAutomator

Tags: java, android, junit, ui-automation

I followed this link [Script to use UIAutomation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/automatic-android-testing-with-uiautomator)

to learn about how to work with UIAutomator.

I followed all steps for script creation.

But when i run the script from Eclipse, i am getting below error. Can someone help me how to overcome this issues?

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: test (java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase.<init>(UiAutomatorTestCase.java:5)
    at SendMessage.<init>(SendMessage.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.createTest(TestSuite.java:63)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestMethod(TestSuite.java:310)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestsFromTestCase(TestSuite.java:153)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.<init>(TestSuite.java:132)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.<init>(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:72)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit3Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit3Builder.java:11)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
)
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:57)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.fail(TestCase.java:227)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite$1.runTest(TestSuite.java:100)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Following is the code:

```
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;


import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiSelector;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;
public class SendMessage extends UiAutomatorTestCase 
{
    public void test() throws UiObjectNotFoundException 
    {
        findAndRunApp();
    }

    // Here will be called for all other functions

    private void findAndRunApp() throws UiObjectNotFoundException 
    {
        // Go to main screen
        getUiDevice().pressHome();

        // Find menu button
        UiObject allAppsButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("Apps"));
        // Click on menu button and wait new window
        allAppsButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

        // Find App tab
        UiObject appsTab = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Apps"));

        // Click on app tab
        appsTab.click();

        // Find scroll object (menu scroll)
        UiScrollable appViews = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));

        // Set the swiping mode to horizontal (the default is vertical)
        appViews.setAsHorizontalList();

        // Find Messaging application
        UiObject settingsApp = appViews.getChildByText(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView"), "Messaging");

        // Open Messaging application
        settingsApp.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

        // Validate that the package name is the expected one

        UiObject settingsValidation = new UiObject(new UiSelector().packageName("com.android.mms"));

        assertTrue("Unable to detect Messaging",settingsValidation.exists());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can anybody throw some light on this?

Comment: can you update the question with your code  ?

Comment: It looks like its running it as a regular test case, not an instrumentation test case. I don't know how to make that work on Eclipse though.  heres one link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212396/warningjunit-framework-testsuite1-exception-in-constructor-when-executing-an

Comment: can you try to run using command line - `adb shell uiautomator runtest /data/local/tmp/SendMessage.jar –c SendMessage` ?